# Is there a direct relation between SQL Server procedures and Pre JIT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, backend, clr, jit

When I was searching for JIT compilation a question has arisen about relation between JIT and SQL Server, I already know that SQL Server has a JIT environment either, which is working on CLR also so that it got me thinking lately.

Answer (score 0):

TSQL Stored Procedures and Batches are interpreted at runtime, not compiled.  Individual queries in a Stored Procedure or Batch will be optimized and have their plans cached on first use (which is a kind of just-in-time compilation).

SQL Server also has CLR procedures, which use .NET Framework's JITter, and Natively-Compiled Stored Procedure, which is an Ahead-of-Time translation from TSQL to C/C++ and compilation using a traditional C/C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks David, so there's a close relation between JIT & SPs,, the fact that servers should be managing their memory very efficiently to provide continuous services. Lastly are SPs created optimized in the first place or they're optimized at runtime? - other than JIT which is a dynamic runtime compilation as well -

Comment: The Query Optimizer runs for every query, unless the query has a cached plan.  And the first time a query is run the Optimizer may examine the values passed for query parameters to guide the optimization.